Translating latitude/longitude coords to 3D point on the surface of a sphere, problem near poles
Assuming the sphere is at position [0,0] (for now), I made this method to calculate a point on the surface of a sphere with a certain radius, given latitude/longitude coordinates (Vector2 x/y):
public static Vector3 GetPointOnSphere(Vector2 coo, float radius)
{
    float lati = coo.x * Mathf.Deg2Rad;
    float longi = coo.y * Mathf.Deg2Rad;
    float x = radius * Mathf.Cos(lati) * Mathf.Cos(longi);
    float y = radius * Mathf.Cos(lati) * Mathf.Sin(longi);
    float z = radius * Mathf.Sin(lati);
    return new Vector3(x, y, z);
}

and this is to translate it back:
public static Vector2 GetCoords(Vector3 point, float radius)
{
    float lati = Mathf.Asin(point.z / radius) * Mathf.Rad2Deg;
    float longi = Mathf.Atan2(point.y, point.x) * Mathf.Rad2Deg;

    return new Vector2(lati, longi);
}

I take the surface point by raycasting from Camera, and use it to move an object around the sphere to the target coordinates:
bool MoveTowardsPoint(Vector2 target, float stop_dist)
{
    Vector2 curr = GetCoords();
    if (CompareVector2(curr, target, stop_dist))
    {
        return true;
    }
    double angularDistance = Math.Acos(Math.Sin(curr.x * Math.PI / 180) * Math.Sin(target.x * Math.PI / 180) +
                                           Math.Cos(curr.x * Math.PI / 180) * Math.Cos(target.x * Math.PI / 180) *
                                           Math.Cos(Math.Abs(curr.y - target.y) * Math.PI / 180)) + 1e-6;
    double fr = MoveSpeed * Time.fixedDeltaTime / angularDistance;
    
    Vector2 coords = new Vector2(LerpAngle(curr.x, target.x, fr),
        LerpAngle(curr.y, target.y, fr));

    transform.position = GetPointOnSphere(coords);
        
    return false;
}

It works on some parts of sphere, but around "horizontal poles" I think, when "fr" grows to infinity (tried Clamping it, but it didn't solve the core problem), the target is never reached and it looks like the pawn is forced away from these poles. The area is quite big and on both sides of the globe. What can I do?
Methods used in MoveTowardsPoint:
float LerpAngle(double a, double b, double t)
{
    double delta = Repeat((b - a), 360);
    if (delta > 180)
        delta -= 360;
    return (float)(a + delta * Clamp01(t));
}

double Repeat(double t, double length)
{
    return Clamp(t - Math.Floor(t / length) * length, 0.0f, length);
}

double Clamp(double value, double min, double max)
{
    if (value < min) return min;
    if (value > max) return max;
    return value;
}

double Clamp01(double value)
{
    if (value < 0.0) return 0.0;
    if (value > 1.0) return 1.0;
    return value;
}


I'm not sure, but it might be helpful to see how the object behaves around the poles. Maybe, it's possible to add a GIF to the question?

I would look to use a well tested GIS library for this - geographer's have been dealing with big circles on the globe for quite a while and are pretty good at it.

If the goal is to move the object between two points on a sphere you should most likely be using quaternions instead of polar coordinates/euler angles. Interpolating angles can be very difficult, since there are poles involved, as well as discontinuities.
Quaternions exist to handle this problem. eulerAngles should allow you to convert to/from angle representation, and use Lerp to for interpolation, or RotateTowards that also allow for a maximum rotation.
I'm not exactly clear on what you are trying to do, but quaternions would commonly be used to create a "virtual trackball" to rotate a shape. In general I would try to use the built in classes as much as possible, and write as little math-y code as possible. And if you need to do math yourself, write lots of unit tests to verify that it works as you expect, since it is very easy to make mistakes.

I need to have the position convertible to geographical coordinates, I want to bottom-up calculate the position on the sphere given latitude, longitude and radius, not to "move" object. Movement is just one way of using it. I would prefer to handle these poles and discontinuities if u would point me into a direction.

@smsware I still do not understand exactly what you are trying to do, but Lerp-ing angles will most likely be incorrect, or give unexpected results. And you should probably convert to quaternions and lerp them instead. Also, if you are talking real geo-coordinates you will need to consider precision, float will most likely not be enough.

I use double, converting to float at the end. it works as expected until the poles. too bad if there is no other way but Quaternions, I thought I could calculate anything...

Quaternions aren't quite what one wants here, since they represent 3D orientation/rotation (an element of SO(3)) rather than position on a 3D sphere (an element of SO(2)).

If you have two points on a sphere, given by A=(x1, y1, z1) and B=(x2, y2, z2), and you want to find a point which is near A but has moved slightly towards B, start by finding the axis of the great circle arc connecting them as AxB (the vector cross product). Simply transform A by a rotation matrix having AxB as its axis and the desired angle delta as its angle.

I want a method of translating latitude/longitude coords to 3D space point and the other way around, it works but not for poles and I just want to find an error or a workaround, I don't just want a path to move, I use these methods for more, so I want to fix how they work

The latitude/longitude representation is an unrelated distraction. Convert your points on the sphere to Cartesian coordinates, do the interpolation, and then convert the result to lat/lon if desired. Don’t try to do any significant coordinate manipulation directly on lat/lon.

Incidentally, your solution doesn’t work properly anywhere on the sphere except when moving directly north/south or along the equator. It’s just that when it’s far away from the poles it’s harder to see that it’s not taking the shortest path.

Oh, and your GetPointOnSphere() looks fine, but your GetCoords() uses asin and is therefore wrong (asin, acos, and atan should never be used, only atan2). Use atan2 to find the latitude, using z and sqrt(x*x+y*y) as the coords.
